# Migrate foxy to humble

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a general question. We are using foxy and it seems that foxy will soon be EOL.

I am wondering if we should change and if so if our nodes which are written in python will still work as well.

So what do I need to consider when switching from foxy to humble?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412228/migrate-foxy-to-humble/) by [Kadlu](https://answers.ros.org/users/136844/kadlu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only the file `setup.cfg`. There you should replace the sign `-` with the sign `_`

I had many packages implemented for Foxy. Now I have Humble. I didn't have any problem importing and compiling them.

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2023-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1